# Filters in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, I was using a controller for `ActionExecuting, ActionExecuted, OnException, Dispose` etc. which was derived from the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

But after changing the application to .NET Core that derives from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`, I'm getting below errors.

> 'MyBaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Controller.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)'

> 'MMBaseController.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Controller.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)'

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
        string action = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Request");

            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Ajax Request");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 'ActionExecutedContext' does not contain a definition for 'RequestContext' and no accessible extension method 'RequestContext' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionExecutedContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I tried below method, still not able to use `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` and `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()`, getting below error:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
        string action = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Request");

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Ajax Request");
            }
            TempData["CurrentSessionErrorMessage"] = "Ajax Authentication Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

> 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'IsAuthenticated' and no accessible extension method 'IsAuthenticated' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'IsAjaxRequest' and no accessible extension method 'IsAjaxRequest' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do we need to have entire code changes for this implementation in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, we will not define `filter` in the controller in Asp.Net Core, we usually create a class inheritance `Filter`. For example

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Do something before the action executes.
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}
```

then you can use `[SampleActionFilter]` attribute on you controller.

you can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#action-filters) about filter in Asp.Net core.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create the filter separately:

```
  public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute  
        {  
         public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)  
            {  
            string controller = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
            string action = Convert.ToString(filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
            SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Request");
    
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                SmartLogger.Info("UnAuthenticated Ajax Request");
            }
           }
         }  
      
     }
```

After that, you can use it on  your controller

```
[CustomFilter]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
//you logic here
}
```

this answer from [Custom Filters](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/custom-action-filters-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

Comment: I tried this. But still I'm getting same error. I have attached error screenshot in the question.